# Null Reference Exception from Acumatica code when trying to generate report PDF

Tags: acumatica

I am trying to render a report PDF and create a FileInfo object, but there is some null reference error getting thrown in Acumatica Code when I attempt to render the report.

Here is my code:

```
        //Report Paramenters
        Dictionary<string, string> parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>()
        {
            {"BiopsyRefNumber", bioRefNbr}
        };

        PX.Reports.Controls.Report report = PXReportTools.LoadReport(reportId, null);
        PXReportTools.InitReportParameters(report, parameters, SettingsProvider.Instance.Default);
        ReportNode reportNode = ReportProcessor.ProcessReport(report);
        IRenderFilter renderFilter = ReportProcessor.GetRenderer(ReportProcessor.FilterPdf);


        Guid? fileGuid = Guid.Empty;
        using (StreamManager mgr = new StreamManager())
        {
            renderFilter.Render(reportNode, null, mgr);
            var file = new FileInfo(Guid.NewGuid(), fileName, null, mgr.MainStream.GetBytes());

            UploadFileMaintenance uploadGraph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<UploadFileMaintenance>();
            uploadGraph.SaveFile(file);
            fileGuid = file.UID;
        }
```

And at renderFilter.Render(), I get a null reference exception with the following stack trace

```
   at PX.Data.Reports.PXSettingProvider.get_Company()
   at PX.Reports.Render.Pdf.PdfReport.Render(Stream stream)
   at PX.Reports.Render.Pdf.PdfRenderer.PX.Reports.Data.IRenderFilter.Render(ReportNode report, Hashtable deviceInfo, StreamManager sm)
   at MY CODE
```

Is there something wrong with the way the SettingsProvider is working perhaps? Whats frustrating is I did this exact same thing with a client for 2019R1, and for some reason its failing for me in 2020R1.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, something is failing with when there is a branch under the tenant. This is a test instance so I deleted all branches.